# How can I get bootstrap classes to work in reactjs app?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, sass, gulp-sass

I have npminstalled  bootstrap-sass "^3.3.7", and reactjs. Is this enough to work with the BS classes like 'well' for example?

This is part of my component:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="well">
            hi from well

            <button className="btn btn-danger"></button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

How can I include the bootstrapstyles in my sass build?

Comment: have you tried react-bootstrap? https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html. Otherwise, I think your current code will work if you have bootstrap-sass included in your npm file. If all else fails, you can also use the bootstrap cdn link, and your code should work.

Comment: How can I include reactbootstrap into the sass?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways in which you can go about doing this:-

- Use [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io). But it clearly says that this project is under development so using this in production I think is clearly not a great idea.
- Add bootstrap to your project and import the bootstrap js file in your html before your compiled bundle.js coming from react.